# How to install Ubuntu straight to HDD with Unetbootin?

Tags: system-installation, usb, hard-drive, unetbootin

I've heard that Unetbootin provides installing a distro straight to Hard drive instead of USB. 
Should I just select Hard Drive as the picture shows and click Ok or there is something else to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of Unetbootin is to create an installation media.
But it does not create the Ubuntu installation media properly anymore.
Use Ubuntu **Disks** tool (`gnome-disk-utility`) to create the media instead.

Open **Disks** - select **Restore Disk Image** from the menu on the top right.
Choose the **ISO file** and the **USB drive** to write it to and **start restoring**.

When you have to create the media from within Windows :
Open **command prompt as administrator** and execute:

```
diskpart
list disk  
select disk *  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 quick  
assign letter=**
```

Note : * = number of USB drive | ** = select a free drive letter

Mount the ISO file and copy the content to the USB drive.

Boot from the USB drive and start to install Ubuntu.

Comment: I think I should give it a try,see if it helps,I won't forget marking your answer as heplful :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be more worthwhile to acquire a small flash drive and boot from there instead. Unless, of course, your BIOS does not support boot from USB.

Unetbootin is designed to create "bootable Live USB drives".

Within my knowledge, I do not believe it is designed to install a distro.

Comment: So you say it's possible but not reccomended?

Comment: Using a tool like Unetbootin modifies the contents of a drive.  I'm not going to say it's a bad idea, but the fact that it could even "prompt" you to format the drive (which it does, or used to do) makes it a dangerous thing to even attempt.

Comment: It's not a big problem for me to get my HDD formatted, I only care about how good the new installed system will work(if it's even going to work). I've once tried installing this way,but when I restarted the system, it booted straight with the installed distro and didn't show two options  (like unetbootin and ubuntu)

Comment: The best way to optimize installation would be using Unetbootin or Startup Disk Utility to create a bootable USB drive with the desired .iso on it.