# How to remove Windows 10 OS completely & install Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

Currently I'm on Windows 10, I want to install Ubuntu OS. I want to fully remove windows OS & want only Ubuntu running on my PC.

Is it possible ?

I will be using Ubuntu mostly to solve JAVA programs & SQL Queries.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible. The Ubuntu installer easily lets you erase Windows and replace it with Ubuntu.

Here is what you have to do :

1. **Backup your data !**
   All of your data will be wiped with your Windows installation so do not miss this step.
2. Create a bootable USB Ubuntu installation.
   Here is the official guide on [Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and on [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).
   Alternatively you can follow those [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702721/how-to-install-ubuntu-straight-to-hdd-with-unetbootin/702741#702741) to create the bootable media.
3. Boot the Ubuntu installation USB drive and choose **Install Ubuntu**.
4. Follow the installation process
   At the step **Installation Type**  select **Replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu**.

[image]

Comment: My windows has been installed on C drive. So only C drive will be formatted no??

Comment: Yes, formatted and everything will be erased.

Comment: The booting process (Step 3) is usually hard on Windows 10 (it doesn't easily allow booting from the USB key). The last time I did it, I needed to configure the BIOS and play with Windows 10's settings (which I am not familiar with). Did you ever encounter similar problems?