# Installation of Ubuntu failed because of "The ext4 file system creation in partition .. failed" or "creation of swap space in partition ... failed"

Tags: partitioning, usb-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS.
My notebook Lenovo T14 had SSD with (before my actions) only one C: with Windows10 on it,
so I did a partition D: to install Ubuntu on it.

Now, after some actions I have neither Windows nor Ubuntu((
neither C: nor D: - but just some mess that I don't understand

I pluged in my usb-drive and tried to do all simple things for installation,
but always failed, so now I did some images of the process to show what I am doing and
how to fix it.

[pressed Install Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKDun.jpg)
I pressed "Install Ubuntu", went through some steps to get into "Installation type"

[Installation type view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZXhM.jpg)
Using "-" and made all free space (except 536Mb for efi, but as I did it process at least 10 times I tried to delete "efi" also and re-create)

[create root partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e96gg.jpg)
Choosing "free space" first I created /root for 100Gb
(here partition is "Primary" but I tried "logical" also - result the same bad)

[create swap area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY3q7.jpg)
Swap area - 20Gb as I have 16Gb RAM
(also I used "Logical" earlier)

I created "/home" - all rest space, but sometimes I tried to keep some "free space" for something else

[Installation type final view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2ATP.jpg)
finally I had this

[last dialog before install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqq4z.jpg)
after pressing "Install now" I had this dialog

[swap creation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvRB8.jpg)
and if I went further - I finally got this error

[Installation type view changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzvtD.jpg)
when I press "ok" I was returnd again in "Installation type"
as you can see - all partitions again are unknown

All these steps I did more than 10 times using different variations:

- Choosing Primary or Logical
- Different sizes of partitions
- when I did not created "/root " - "No root file system is defined" error
- When I used an option "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" - "The ext4 file system creation in partition #2 of /dev/nvme0n1 failed"
- if I didn't create swap file, I saw again "The ext4 file system creation in partition #2 of /dev/nvme0n1 failed"

So I have 2 types of similar errors about "creation in partition .. failed"

I am new ubuntu user. I am struggling with this full day, please, help me to overcome this issue to install Ubuntu

Comment: There is no "partition D" in linux. In your screenshots I did not see any windows. So [this](https://www.pcsuggest.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/install_ubuntu_7.png) is how it should look.

Comment: @kanehekili I meant that at the beginning I had windows 10 and two disks C and D, but after some bad actions I have what I have on images

Comment: Did you turn off "Windows fast boot"?

Comment: @Raffles now windows is unavailable, I think I deleted it by accident, so now, the only possibility to turn on my notebook is when usb stick is in usb port. All other options are not available((

Comment: @AlexeySimchenko if you boot into a live session, you should be able to see if your Windows partitions are still there by using GParted. You will have to install GParted in your live session though, I don't think it is included.

Comment: Did you update UEFI? And NVMe firmware? Many (even new) need updates. https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devices/  Similar older Lenovo's, you may have same settings.  Lenovo T460S unable to update firmware fwupdate, disabled boot order lock
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2455027 UEFI update required for USB-C port issues 2017 thru 2019 models Thinkpad - Shows UEFI screens for settings
https://tothepoles.co.uk/2017/11/16/lenovo-t470p-ubuntu-16-04-install-notes/  &  'optimized os set up' must be off

Comment: I think he went about this the wrong way from the start. See this link https://www.pcsteps.com/3305-prepare-windows-dual-boot-installation/

Comment: @Raffles I don't care about windows. If l lost that - doesn't matter. I just want to install ubuntu. I didn't know that it is so hard, long and painful process((

Comment: In this case, let the installer choose the configuration. You can change it later if necessary. Remember to check the box to install updates. secure boot in UEFI/BIOS  must be OFF but set to UEFI.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/704970/how-to-remove-windows-10-os-completely-install-ubuntu

Comment: @Raffles I tried all available options again. And failed again( So, I decided to open Gparted but also failed. I created a question about it with steps and images https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321840/failed-to-open-gparted-on-ubuntu