# Failed to open Gparted on Ubuntu

Tags: boot, gparted

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS using usb drive but failed because of partition problems, which I described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321671/installation-of-ubuntu-failed-because-of-the-ext4-file-system-creation-in-parti)
So, to understand what's going with my drive I tried to use Gparted while using live Ubuntu (on flesh drive) but also failed.

I found that Gparted already pre installed. As I didn't find the way to open it by cliking on an icon - I used a command

```
sudo gparted
```

and immediately got an error:
[image: Input/output error during read on /dev/nvme0n1]

I couldn't close Gparted neither closing graphical windows nor using commands:
[image: Operation not permitted]

So, as an error is about a drive I launched a command to see disk space:

```
df -h
```

with result:
[image: some drives]

Why I am getting that error? What to do?

Comment: You have LVM - logical volumes. The LVM is inside one large partition and needs LVM tools to manage it. Gparted will only work on standard partitions. You also show gpt partitioning, but no ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot or a bios_grub partition for BIOS boot. At this point probably better to start over. Do you want LVM which is a bit more advanced, but required if you also want full drive encryption, or standard partitions?  You may need sudo to run terminal commands even on live installer, but then password not required as it would be with a full install.

Comment: Do not start gparted with sudo. To kill gparted started with sudo, use pskill with sudo. In other words of you start something with sudo, kill that thing with `sudo pskill` as well.

Comment: @oldfred I have LVM on this printscreen (I have no idea what LVM means) because I tried all posiblities to install Ubuntu. In other scenarios I had another volumes. Can you go to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321671/installation-of-ubuntu-failed-because-of-the-ext4-file-system-creation-in-parti ? Maybe you will see what I am doing wrong..

Comment: You do not run graphical commands with sudo in the teminal, sudo is for terminal commands in administrative mode. You should just be able to launch gparted from live installer in live mode like any other application. It probably does not have a default icon, but you search for it and launch it from the gui. If you do not know LVM and do not need full drive encryption, only use standard partitions. or standard install.